# TFS 2012 compile a VS 2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can TFS 2012 compile a VS 2010 solution file? (not connecting to a TFS 2010 Agent)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Yes you can compile`, `Build Agent` execute exactly with `same mode`, you have news just about executiong of unit tests on your integration (If you have unit tests), on 2012 we use `Test Runner layer` and not Ms Test, you can have different behavior about this subject (These news don't affect compiling process)

nice link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/03/30/team-foundation-server-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-agents-and-controllers.aspx